# "if" statement with input that takes int & string

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

New to Python (2.7). I'm trying to collect a user input that can either be an int or string (I'm assuming this is possible, though I'm not 100% sure). When I get to the statement that I've posted below, any number I enter prints the 'Invalid input' message and prompts me for a user input again, even if it's within the range I want it to be. Entering 'q' still works properly and returns if entered.

I've tried changing that first `if` statement to read `(0 <= collectEyesBlade <= 9)` ... with no luck either.

```
while True:
    collectEyesBlade = raw_input(
        "\nEnter desired blade number: ")
    if collectEyesBlade in [range(0,9)]:
        break
    elif collectEyesBlade.lower() == 'q':
        return
    else:
        print "\nInvalid input. Enter value between 0 and 9, or 'q' to quit"
        continue
```

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, convert it to int

Answer (score 1):

Since `raw_input` returns a `str`, start with the comparison that uses another string. Then, try to convert it to an `int`. Finally, if that succeeds, try the integer comparision.

```
while True:
    collectEyesBlade = raw_input("\nEnter desired blade number: ")

    if collectEyesBlade.lower() == 'q':
        return

    try:
        collectEyesBlade = int(collectEyesBlade)
    except ValueError:
        print "\nInvalid input. Enter value between 0 and 9, or 'q' to quit"
        continue

    if collectEyesBlade in range(0,9):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

`if collectEyesBlade in [str(x) for x in range(0,9)]` - this should work since `collectEyesBlade` is a string so we need to compare it to a string

Answer (score 0):

You've hit at two of the little quirks of Python. One: a range is itself an iterable, but it's possible to put an iterable inside of another iterable.

In other words, your statement

```py
if collectEyesBlade in [range(0,9)]:
```

is checking to see whether collectEyesBlade is an item in the list, which has only one item: a range iterable. Since you're not entering a range iterable, it's failing.

You can instead say

```py
if collectEyesBlade in list(range(0,9)):
```

which will turn the range iterable into an actual list, or just

```py
if collectEyesBlade in range(0,9):
```

Either should do what you intend.

However, as another answerer has mentioned, that's only half the problem. If your input were actually possibly integer type, the above would be sufficient, but you're asking for a string input. Just because the input is a "1" doesn't mean it's not a string one.

There are a couple of options here. You could do a try-except converting the string input into an integer, and if it fails because the string can't be converted into an integer, move on; or you could convert the range/list of numbers to compare to into strings.